# AH can't be higher than 0xFF, can it?

Tags: assembly, x86

As you can see in the code below, I called int 0x13. It failed and I now want to find out why.

```
mov si,bx                   ; BX points to my DAP
mov ah,0x42
mov dl,[BOOTDRIVE]
int 0x13
jc .fail

           ...
.fail:
cmp ah,0xFF                           ;what is the error code?
jg .something_wrong

           ...

.something_wrong:
mov ah,0xe
mov al,'E'                   ; 'E' stands for "ERROR"
int 0x10
jmp $
```

But I can't! Because the jg instruction is executed! When I run this code in QEMU it prints an 'E'. But hey, AH can't contain a value higher than 0xFF! So how is that possible?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jg` will [jump depending](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow#Jump_if_Greater) upon the setting of flags `ZF`, `SF` and `OF` after the execution of the `cmp` which sets these flags. In this context `cmp ah,0xFF` and `jg` together are comparing `ah` as a signed value with `-1` (which is what `0xFF` is when viewed as a 2's complement 8-bit value). If `ah` is between `0` and `0x7f` (greater than `-1`), it will be true (takes the jump). Otherwise, false (does not take the jump).